# Let $x_1,\dots,x_m \in \mathbb R^d$ span an $n$-dimensional subspace. Prove if $n\geq d$ and $Ax_i=x_i$ for all $i$, then $A$ is the identity.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $\{ x_i \}_{i=1}^{m}$ be a set of $m$ vectors in $\mathbb R^d$, and suppose $\langle x_i,\dots,x_m \rangle=S$ is a subspace of dimension $n$. Consider the set $\mathcal S$ of matrices $A \in \mathbb R^{d\times d}$ satisfying $Ax_i = x_i$ for all $1 \leq i \leq m$.

Show that if $n = d$, then there is a unique solution given by $A=I$, the identity matrix. Otherwise, if $n < d$, there are infinitely many solutions.

In the case $n<d$, I am also interested how to "measure" the set $\mathcal S$, and whether it is related to the quantity $d-n$.

---

Attempt: Let $S$ be the subspace generated by $\{x_i\}_{i=1}^{m}$, which is assumed to have dimension $n$.

From $Ax_i = x_i$ we have $(A-I)x_i = 0$ for all $i$. This implies $S$ is ismorphic to $\ker(A-I)$ (I think).

Comment: How about vectors $(1,0,0),(0,1,0), (2,0,0),(0,2,0)$ in $\mathbb R^3$ and the matrix $diag(1,1,0)$?

Comment: @markvs I agree, you defeated my initial question. I believe I have corrected my assumptions.

Comment: The new question is trivial because every finite set of vectors that spans the whole space contains a basis of that space, and if a matrix fixes a basis, it is the identity. If $n\ge d$, then $n=d$.

If $n<d$ then for every complement $V'$ of the subspace $V$ spanned by your vectors, choose a linear transformation that is identity on $V$ and anything on $V'$. Its matrix belongs to your set $S$.

Answer (score 1):

Summary markvs' comment: if we consider the set of linear transforms $T:\mathbb R^d \to \mathbb R^d$ given by $T(x)=(A-I)x$ satisfying $T(x)=0$ for all $x \in S = \langle x_1, \dots, x_n \rangle$, then it follows that $S$ is a subspace of $\ker T$.

Case 1. If $n\geq d$ then $\{x_1,\dots,x_m\}$ forms a basis for $\mathbb R^d$. Since $S$ is contained in $\ker T$, it follows $\ker T$ is all of $\mathbb R^d$. Hence $T$ is the zero map, and $A=I$.

Case 2. If $n<d$, then $S$ is a subspace of $\ker T$, but the dimension of the kernel may vary with $$n \leq \dim(\ker T) \leq d$$ and
$$ \dim(\mathbb R^d / \ker T)=d-n \geq 0. $$